# Generar codigo de barras ITF-14

Tags: php, javascript, php5, tcpdf

Estoy intentando generar códigos de barras ITF-14 desde PHP o Javascript pero no encuentro manera.
Hasta ahora estaba usando la libreria TCPDF que me permitia generar otros tipos como DUN-14, pero no acepta el formato ITF-14.
Conoceis alguna libreria/API que permita generar estos codigos de barras?

Un saludo y gracias!!

Comment: Corregido, pensaba que estabna en inglés.

Comment: Hola, te dejo un link a una libreria que genera codigos de barras ITF-14: http://www.barcodelib.com/java_barcode/barcode_symbologies/itf14.html en el link tambien hay un poco de detalle sobre como utilizar la libreria.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta libreria es para Java, no?

Comment: Si, es para java, compatible con un jdk 1.4 o posterior

Comment: Y como se podria añadir a un programa PHP? Si es que se puede..

Comment: Ah! perdon fallo mio, no me habia dado cuenta de que era para PHP, para php no tengo mucha idea, googleando un poco he encontrado este link de github, quizas te ayude: https://github.com/kreativekorp/barcode